# How To change bootstrap media Queries?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to overwrite Bootstrap Media Queries with my custom.css

Here is bootstrap query

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-right {
      display: none;
}
```

I'm getting nowhere. What I'm trying to do is

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px){

     display:none;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated on how I overwrite bootstrap queries with my custom.css

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the class in your own media query as well. Simply by putting in `display: none` without pointing it to anything will not affect anything. You are missing the `.navbar-right { }` pointer entirely.

Comment: Use [Specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/) or `!important`, but it's better practice to use specificity

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
    .navbar-right {
          display: none;
    }
}
```

Write Your media query as above

Answer (score 0):

Add the class or element id to overwrite the CSS.Without specifying the selector you will not able to achieve what you want.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-right {
      display: none;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
.navbar-right {
      display: none;
}
```

You can try Responsive Utilities available in Bootstrap to hide some thing

use *.hidden-xs* and *.hidden-sm* to the elements in your layout to hide the elements in the mobile and tablet.It will help you to achieve what you want.

Please find the link for more information [Click Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507005111/https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your custom.css file

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .navbar-right {
      display: none !important;
  }
}
```